# Is there a way to pass props with a dynamic index like link{1}, link{2}, etc?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a component that for now accepts 2 groups of inputs + labels.

```
import React from 'react'
import MyLogic from './MyLogic';

interface MyProps {
    url1: string
    text1: string   
    url2: string
    text2: string   
}

const MyLogic: React.FC<MyProps> = props => {

    const { url1, text1, url2, text2 } = props;

    return (
       <>
          <MyLogic {...{ url: url1, text: text1 }} />
          <MyLogic {...{ url: url2, text: text2 }} />
       </>
    )

}

export default MyLogic;
```

Get it?

I need to handle the props dynamically because at some point there could 100 inputs and every input needs an index, where the first input needs `{ url: url1, text: text1 }` and the 100 needs `{ url: url100, text: text100 }`.

So if that happens I will have to call `MyLogic` component 100 times.

```
<MyLogic {...{ url: url1, text: text1 }} />
<MyLogic {...{ url: url2, text: text2 }} />
...
<MyLogic {...{ url: url97, text: text97 }} />
<MyLogic {...{ url: url98, text: text98 }} />
... // and so on
```

**IMPORTANT**

I didn't explain an important part.

The reason why I need this is because I am using an external service that reads a prop by its name;

```js
read: [{ name: 'text1', url: 'url1' }, { name: 'text2', url: 'url2', ... }]
```

That's the way it reads the value of the prop. Maybe doing something like: `{ name: 'input.text1' }` etc. Don't know if you got my point.

So how can I handle this in the most dynamic way possible?

Comment: Why not give it an *array* of objects?

Comment: Read my update, I didn't explain that part and now I realized it is important.

Comment: So convert that at some boundary layer, you can still use the structure that makes sense within your app.

Answer (score 4):

Use an array of objects were each object is the properties of a single input. Now you can map the inputs array, and spread the properties.

```
interface InputProps {
  url: string
  text: string   
}

interface MyProps {
  inputs: InputProps[]
}

const MyLogic: React.FC<MyProps> = ({ inputs }: MyProps) => (
  <>
    {inputs.map(p => (
      <MyLogic {...p} />
    ))}
  </>
);
```

Comment: I didn't explain an important part. The reason why I need this is because I am using an external service that reads a prop by its name. `read: { name: 'text1', url: 'url1' }`. That's the way it reads the value of the prop. Maybe doing something like: `{ name: 'input.text1' }` etc. Don't know if you got my point.

Comment: Update the question with a more information - for example how do multiple reads look like? Do you get an array of read objects, etc... And add an example data structure with multiple items.

Comment: Did it already. And yes, it is like this: `read: [{ name: 'text1', url: 'url1' }, name: 'text2', url: 'url2', ... }]`

Comment: The comment was written after seeing your update. I don't understand exactly what are you passing to your component now. Please include the datastructure that you currently pass with the relevant data.

Comment: And if you your data structure is an object with a `read` property which is an array, all you need is to just pass `obj.read` as the `inputs` property in my answer.